# Unable to open .xml file in android studios version 3.2.1

Tags: android, xml, android-studio-3.2

Android studios version 3.2.1 does not build and keeps on loading an infinite amount of time.[This is the screen I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1fdR.png)
 This error is occurring in the latest version of android studios. I reinstalled the software and made sure everything is up to date but I still cannot build a newly created .xml file. However, I can view and edit the code.
[I get this error every time I try to open any .xml file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SjGus.png) Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
1. Go to File->Setting-->Gradle-->Set it to offline mode and check
```

Comment: Thanks vishal. I tried this and there is no error mentioned but I still cannot build.